# Ubuntu Tex Live installation error

Tags: installing, texlive, ubuntu

Due to the old version of Tex Live available in Ubuntu 11.04, I tried to install Tex-Live 2011 using the instructions given on the [TUG website](http://tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html).

However, when I run the install-tl script I get the following message.

```
    Installing TeX Live 2011 from: http://archive.cs.uu.nl/mirror/CTAN/systems/texlive/tlnet....       
    <D> directories:
           TEXDIR (the main TeX directory):
             !! default location: /usr/local/texlive/2011
             !! is not writable, please select a different one!
```

Can anybody help me how to fix this ? When I try to run the script it just shuts down.

Comment: Do you run the script as root? You can also create the folder with sudo mkdir and than change the owner with `chown`.

Comment: Okay, I created the folded with sudo mkdir.However, still trying to figure out the `chown` command

Comment: I figured however to become root using (http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-can-i-log-in-as-root/) and tex live is installing as we speak. However I hope some developer gets in and creates a Tex Live 2011 package for ubuntu.

Comment: `sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /usr/local/texlive/` should work. You can also install TL as root. In my opinion it is no problem.

Comment: One should execute the `install-tl` script with superuser privileges: `sudo ./install-tl`; the script will create the relevant directories.

Comment: This question is about ubuntu's technical details, not tex or texlive. Wouldn't it be more appropriate in ubuntuforums.org ?

Comment: @egreg: that is a personal choice. I've installed TL2011 in a user directory with user rights, and it works perfectly fine. That said, stuff in `/usr/local` should belong to root.

Comment: @Raphink: in this case one has to specify the main TeX directory.

Comment: @egreg: ... which can be done within the installation process.

Comment: @Andrew: that's what I meant; it's sufficient to choose the path using the `D` command and then the `1` command. The installer will create the relevant directory.

Comment: @Mateus I admit that this is question more related to ubuntu, however this forum always gives me so good feedback that I just couldn't refuse.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you wish to install TeXLive in `/usr/local/texlive/2011` (which is the default location), then  you need to do so as root. Either use `sudo` in front of your `./install-tl` command, or switch to root account (`sudo -i`) and install it:

```
sudo ./install-tl
```

If you want to install TeXLive as a simple user (and not as root), you can do so by specifying another location for the installation:

```
TEXLIVE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/path/to/install/dir ./install-tl
```

Comment: **sudo warning**: if installing via `sudo ./install-tl` then make sure that your `umask` is `022` at the time that you run the command.

Comment: +1. You have to change that environment variable if installing to a different location than the system default (or if you do not have sudo privileges, etc).