# ! LaTeX Error: File `adjustbox.sty' not found on Ubuntu 10.04.2

Tags: errors, installing, adjustbox

I have install `$ sudo apt-get install texlive-full` on Ubuntu 10.04.2 but when I run I got this error about adjustbox.

```
! LaTeX Error: File `adjustbox.sty' not found
```

Is there anyone know how to install/fix this error.

Comment: what you don't say is what operating system you're using. if (like me) you're using ubuntu 12.04 lts, this is not surprising: adjustbox appeared latter than the ubuntu release. so tell which version of which os, and someone can make a useful recommendation.

Comment: There really should be some standard way to verify installation. Like post-installation verify type command. but searching around, I found these instructions: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/101878/quickest-way-of-applying-thesis-to-tex-template/101890#101890  First you need to make sure it was installed fully. Also, you need to show a minimal working example, and the command you used to compile the latex file.

Comment: This just happen when importing package (\usepackage{adjustbox}). The same code i write work well on Mac but not Ubantu

Comment: the difference between macos and ubuntu was exactly why i asked what os you use.  ubuntu freezes its offerings (after a lot of testing) when it makes a release; typically, even its texlive-full is pretty conservative, but it's also frozen in time.  mactex, otoh, is a "real" full install maintained by texies and released in parallel with tl.  which version of ubuntu are you using?  (i.e., complete the answer ... for example, i'm using ubuntu 12.04 lts -- it tells me this in /etc/issue)

Comment: @nasser an "installation verify" would need to know what was _supposed_ to be installed.  the best evidence for that is what _was_ installed, but you can go back to the source of the installation, unpack it and produce a list: but that's circular ("it installed what it said it was going to install").  in today's world of rapidly changing packages and wildly different ideas of what _should_ be installed, a post-installation test is best done by compiling docs that are needed ... as sarawut has done.

Comment: @wasteofspace I am sorry, I am not following. Many software comes with post-installation self verification program, which verifies that installation was correct. It can be as simple as a script which compiles few test programs and display the output and many other ways. This is nothing new really. Specially for complex software, it is even more important to have.

Comment: You could also install only `adjustbox` locally, together with some other of my packages it requires. All of these can be downloaded from http://CTAN.org or http://bitbucket.org/martin_scharrer/. Simply take the TDS ZIP files and unpack them into your local TEXMF tree. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/73016/2975 for further help on that.

Comment: I came here on error in MacOS as well. The solution to `sudo tlmgr install adjustbox` worked fine. I suggest updating question title to not be OS specific.

Answer (score 13):

If you didn't (as I didn't) do the full latex installation (3 GB !^oo^!), the answer might be as simple as a

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-latex-extra
```

Comment: That worked in Ubuntu trusty tahr 14.04 LTS also - thanks!

Comment: Great advice for those of us coming from Windows with no knowledge of behind-the-curtains stuff.

Answer (score 11):

The TeX Live which comes with Ubuntu and Debian doesn't receive updates very often, so it's usually an old TeX Live version which packages can't be directly updated. I, as the `adjustbox` author, recommend to install the 'vanilla' version of TeX Live, i.e. direct from its website and not the Ubuntu package. Please see [Best way to install packages for TeXLive in Ubuntu?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/28533/2975) for further info. Also [How to install "vanilla" TeXLive on Debian or Ubuntu?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu) and [Best way to install packages for TeXLive in Ubuntu?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28528/2975) should help.

You could also install only `adjustbox` locally, together with some other of my packages it requires. All of these can be downloaded from http://CTAN.org or http://bitbucket.org/martin_scharrer/. Simply take the TDS ZIP files and unpack them into your local TEXMF tree. See [How to install LaTeX .zip package (from CTAN) using texhash on a 'nix system?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/30311/2975) for the details on that.

Comment: Thank you very much for all suggestions. It's work now. I follow the instruction from here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27117/ubuntu-tex-live-installation-error.

Answer (score 8):

If you're on a Mac with BasicTex installed and receive this error, you need to install some extra Tex packages. Use `tlmgr`.

```
sudo tlmgr install adjustbox
```

I also had to install some more packages which I assume you will have to too:

```
sudo tlmgr install collectbox
sudo tlmgr install ucs
```

Answer (score 2):

if you use:

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-latex-extra
```

you will download about 600 MB (because apt-get by default installs all the recommended packages).

If you want to decrease the download size to about 24 MB, use:

```
sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends texlive-latex-extra
```

By doing this way, you avoid installing some packages (documentation almost) unneeded in order to generate PDF.

Maybe you have to install some extra fonts (if you got `` ! LaTeX Error: File `eurosym.sty' not found. ``):

```
sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends  texlive-fonts-recommended
```

Comment: I was getting this error while exporting python notebooks as pdf. One more install solves my problem:
`sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends  texlive-generic-recommended`