# Various *sty files missing when using adjustbox

Tags: packages

I have installed `texlive-latex-extra` and `texlive-extra-utils` packages on my Ubuntu 12.04, but when I try to `\usepackage{adjustbox}` the compiler asks me about packages such as `adjustbox.sty`, `adjcalc.sty` or `trimclip.sty`. How can I install all of them from the Ubuntu repositories.

Comment: It seems as if http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/116668/88939 is still true for Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Two simple rules for a quiet life with TeX Live: (1) Use the built-in package manager (tlmgr) rather than your Linux package manager; and (2) install *everything.*

Comment: I could not find the package trimclip in TeX Live Utility, your question gave me a hint to try installing adjustbox and it fixed my issue, thanks!